# Creating JWT to match the JWT generated by .Net core

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi, nimbus-jose-jwt

The third party API I am working with is asking me to generate the JWT on client side. I understand that they use the following code to verify JWT.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

// The key length needs to be of sufficient length, or otherwise an error will occur.
var tokenSecretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenSecretKey"]);

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    // Token signature will be verified using a private key.
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenSecretKey),
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false
};

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options => { options.RequireHttpsMetaData = false;
options.SaveToken = true; 
 options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters; 
});
```

In the client side the token generation I have  created using is as follows using Jose JWT.
Only this seems to be working for .Net 4.0 Framework I am working with.

```
return Jose.JWT.Encode(claims, byteArrayOfKey, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.HS256);
```

but the validation is failing with 401 on server side. Is there anything I can do match the server side.

Comment: Its not clear what do you mean by client side. On normal circumstances you don't need to generate anything, if it is only HS256 you can't even verify anything (just if you know the secret key, which is private on the server).

Comment: Thats right, under normal circumstances the API will send back the JWT after verifying something, like a user id and password. But here they have shared a logic to generate the secret key, which matches with theirs. By client side, I mean the calling application.

Comment: They are sending some jwt to you (so you have some sample)? Or how do you know, that they are accepting HS256?

Answer (score 0):

Check the algorithm at both client and server uses same.
and basically, don't ignore the issuer, anyone can forge the server so as a best practice use issuer as mandatory validation.